# Maximum size for environment variable

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

What is the maximum size of an environment variable with Serverless Framework?

At some point (in 2019 based on issue tracking ticket) it has been 4 Kb and in a project I'm working with there was a workaround made because of this. Now this workaround is part of timeout issues faced, and I'm wondering whether this could be removed, i.e. if the limit has been increased.

I couldn't find the limit by searching docs and based on tribal knowledge the original issue came up when a developer tried to load big enough parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4kb for all environment variables is still the limit: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-environment-variable-size/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize it was a limit in AWS Lambda rather than with Serverless Framework. I'll update the question tags to match this.

Answer (score 1):

As per the official document limit is 4 KB,

But there is a catch here; you can send data even more than 4 KB,
let me tell you how I have achieved this.

I used Zlib(https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) library, which compresses the string into a very short size.
Then again, inside the lambda, I have decompressed the string.

This is how I have sent almost 512 KB of data into lambda environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation specifies a maximum combined size of 4 kb for environment variables. However, from my experience, the real limit is 5 kb or 5120 bytes.